# "Cannot resolve TargetName" error in custom storyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, storyboard

In WP7 silverlight app, i wanted to use a storyboard animation on a particular event.
The animation is changing button height property from x to y points (changed for query).

I am using below code in my program

```
   Storyboard myStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
   myStoryBoard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

   DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
   Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, button1.Name); // button1 is normal button on UI
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.HeightProperty));

   myDoubleAnimation.From = 200;
   myDoubleAnimation.To = 300;

   myStoryBoard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
   myStoryBoard.Begin();
```

when i run my code, i am hitting with 
     **Cannot resolve TargetName *button1*** error

any easy fix for my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use SetTargetName only if the Storyboard is in the visual tree. I suggest using SetTarget instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settarget%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, button1);
```